# PHP - Abstract class with correct property declaration

Tags: php

I have my abstract class:

```
class AbstractClass
{
    public function func($arguments)
    {
        // $this->array[0] (...)
    }
}
```

And my child class:

```
class ChildClass extends AbstractClass
{
    protected $array = [
        //(some content)
    ];
}
```

And when i run `(new ChildClass)->func()` i get the warning "The property array does not exist.". Should i put the property `array` on the AbstractClass or just ignore the warning?

Comment: Can you update the code to show exactly what you're doing? When I add a `key`, `value` to the `protected $array` and call it in the `AbstractClass` it works fine.

Comment: @RhapX, my code is working since this is just a warning. I'm just looking to know what is the best practice.

Comment: I see, set a default for your `$arguments` variable. When you are calling the method, you are not passing anything to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the property to `AbstractClass` with some default value. E.g.

```
class AbstractClass 
{                                                                                  
    protected $array = ['default'];                                                         

    public function show()                                                         
    {                                                                              
        print_r($this->array);                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                  

class A extends AbstractClass                                                      
{                                                                                  
    protected $array =[1,2,3,4,5];                                           
}                                                                                  

class B extends AbstractClass                                                      
{                                                                                  
    protected $array =['A','B','C','D'];                           
}  

class C extends AbstractClass
{
   // use the defaults
}

echo (new A)->show();                                                              
echo (new B)->show();
echo (new C)->show();
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
Array
(
    [0] => default
)
```

No warnings.